# Declaring an int in C++ with <<

Tags: c++, initialization, boolean, implicit-conversion

Can someone explain to me what this declaration means in C++; I have never seen something declared like this, and was just confused on what it meant and how it works:

```
int ix((dx > 0) - (dx < 0));
```

Same with this declaration, too:

```
int error(dy - (dx >> 1));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may declare a scalar object using an initializer in parentheses or braces.

In this declaration

```
int ix((dx > 0) - (dx < 0));
```

there is used the expression `(dx > 0) - (dx < 0)` as an initializer.

if `dx` is greater than 0 then the sub-expression `(dx > 0)` evaluates to boolean true while this sub-expression `(dx < 0)` to boolean `false`. As a result the expression is `true - false` where the boolean values are implicitly converted to 1 for true and to 0 for false. So you will get 1 if `dx` is greater than `0`.

If `dx` is less than `0` you will get `-1`.

If `dx` is equal to `0` then the both sub-expressions evaluate to false and you will get `0`.

So the variable ix is initialized either 1 or 0 or -1 depending on whether `dx` is greater than equal to or less than 0.

In this declaration

```
int error(dy - (dx >> 1));
```

there is used the bit-wise shift right operator `dx >> 1` that shifts bits of the variable `dx` one position right. It is equivalent to the expression `dx / 2`.

For example if `dx` is equal to 6 then its binary representation is (I will use only one byte for simplicity)

```
0000 0110
```

shifting right one position you will get

```
0000 0011
```

that is the binary representation of 3.

It is difficult to say why this initializer is used in this declaration

```
int error(dy - (dx >> 1));
```

without knowing the context where it is used.

Comment: Hey Vlad, you seem to know a lot. Do you find the first expression (with `dx`) useful/clear/good style or would you use another method to achieve the same? Asking because I’m learning and wondering if this is something I should use.

Comment: @rezi It is a normal style. Such an expression usually used in  comparison  functions in C standard functions such as qsort or bsearch.

Answer (score 2):

By default when you write something like `int var;` and `int var = int();` in C++, the value of `var` will be uninitialized in the first case and will be set to zero in the second.

The lines of your example are the same as:

```
int ix = (dx > 0) - (dx < 0);
int error = dy - (dx >> 1);
```

Also,
`dx > 0` and `dx < 0` are either 0 or 1, and `dx >> 1` divides `dx` by 2.

In the line: `int ix((dx > 0) - (dx < 0));`

- ix =  1  if dx > 0
- ix =  0  if dx = 0
- ix = -1  if dx < 0

Comment: Hmm Im still confused those since the < > are comparison signs. Do they work like if statements in this context?

Comment: @JohnsonMain `<` and `>` are *operators*, similar to `+`, `*`, etc. But instead of a number they return a `bool`: either `true` or `false`, which can be implicitly converted to integers `1` and `0`.

Comment: @André Caceres I have asked another question which may give context to this